# Extrating numbers from a string using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, selenium

Can someone help me with writing regular expressions for the below?

First of all, I ask the user for some text (usually in the format of `XXX_X_XX_XXX_1406_V1_2`).

What I need to do is extract the `1406` part of the string (ie the date), so I can run some further analysis on it.

I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this though. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex:

```
String num = input.replaceAll(".*_(\\d+)(_[^_]*){2}$", "$1");
```

Comment: OP will have nightmares tonight.. Dreaming about a regex monster chasing him and trying to kill him.

Answer (score 4):

**No need to use an regex here**, just use:

```
String[] tok = input.split("_");
```

and then use: `tok[4]` for your value.